# Firebase security rules for collections in collection

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to set a firebase security rules for all collections in one collection with Firebase Firestore. I have a collection named Chats inside of it I have two collection one is thread and the other is users. All the documents ids are random.

**This is how my Firebase Data Looks Like:**

[image]
[image]

I am trying to set the security for all the chats & thread & users. Because chats includes the thread collection and the user collection but when setting the rule below: it does not work properly: Missing or insufficient permissions.

```
// Chats can be read & written by all users
  match /Chats/{document} {
    allow read, create, update, delete, write: if true
  }
```

I also tried:

```
   match /Chats/{document}/thread/{document1} {
     allow read, create, update, delete, write: if true
    }


   match /Chats/{document}/users/{document2} {
     allow read, create, update, delete, write: if true
    }
```

But it did not work, so if someone can please help me with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current rules only matches documents in the `/Chats` collection:

```
match /Chats/{userId}
```

To make it also match the subcollections , it'd have to be:

```
match /Chats/{document=**} {
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [securing hierarchical data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#hierarchical_data), specifically the section on [recursive wildcards](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards).

Comment: Hello, what if I want to set a different security rule from a specific subcollection can you please help me with that?

Comment: That sounds like a new question. Keep in mind, that you can't revoke permission once it is granted though. So you can't simply say: "you can read everything, but not this one" after setting a wildcard like in my answer.